# Backbone localstorage A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I am creating a small application based on a backbone example with the backbone-localstorage plugin.

When saving the data for a new model I always get the error "*A "url" property or function must be specified*"

After reading through several simular topics I'm still not able to find the cause for this.

**Model:**

```
directory.models.EmployeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("EmployeeCollection"), 

    model: directory.models.Employee,

    store: directory.utils.store,

    findByName: function(key) {
        this.reset(this.store.findByName(key));
    }

});
```

**The view:**

```
directory.views.newEmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(directory.utils.templateLoader.get('new-employee'));
    },

    events: {
        "click .save": "saveEmployee"
    },

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    saveEmployee: function(event){
        this.model.set({
            firstName:$('#newFirstName').val(),
            lastName:$('#newLastName').val(),
            title:$('#newTitle').val(),
            city:$('#newCity').val(),
            officePhone:$('#newOfficePhone').val(),
            cellPhone:$('#newCellPhone').val(),
            email:$('#newEmail').val()
        });

        this.model.save();
        window.history.back();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the model property of your view already a member of your collection? Can you show how you set the model property on the view?

Comment: The model is not yet in the collection. It's a new one.  newEmployee: function() {this.slidePage(new directory.views.newEmployeeView({model:new directory.models.Employee()}).render());}

Comment: ...not even sure if I have to instantiate the collection and where to do this?

Comment: Try creating an instance of the collection in your router and setting it on the view like you're currently doing with the model. In your view you can do this.collection.create({'firstName', firstName, etc. etc}). I think the model probably needs to be associated with your collection before you persist it. The create method will add the model and save it.

Comment: Why do I need to repeat the entire JSON in the .create() ? When I just created a model with those attributes. Isn't there a simple way to add the model to the collection with all its attributes?

Comment: Just a hardcoded test: in my router I have: var Employeelist = new directory.models.EmployeeCollection; In my view I have Employeelist.create({firstName:"a", lastName:"b"}); RESULT: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined

Comment: You don't need to repeat anything you've already done, you can use the create syntax I've provided instead of instantiating the new model. Or you could create an instance of the model and do this.collection.create(myNewModelInstance)

Comment: Pass the collection to the view like this. new EmployeeView({collection: Employeelist}); In your view you can add new models to it like this: this.collection.create({firstName: 'a', lastName: 'b'})

Comment: In my ROUTER I have: this.slidePage(new directory.views.newEmployeeView({model:new directory.models.Employee(),collection: Employeelist}).render()); In my VIEW: this.collection.create(this.model); Still the same error from backbone.localstorage.js:Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the new model to be a member of your collection before you attempt to persist it. Try creating a new instance of your collection and passing it to the view (probably in your router) like this:

```
new newEmployeeView({ collection: new EmployeeCollection() });
```

In your view you can use Backbone's create convenience method (see [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)) to add a new instance of the model to the collection and persist it:

```
this.collection.create({
    firstName:$('#newFirstName').val(),
    lastName:$('#newLastName').val(),
    title:$('#newTitle').val(),
    city:$('#newCity').val(),
    officePhone:$('#newOfficePhone').val(),
    cellPhone:$('#newCellPhone').val(),
    email:$('#newEmail').val()
});
```

Comment: Ive tried multiple syntax now, Always getting the following error from backbone.localstorage.js: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined. From the method Backbone.LocalStorage.sync

Comment: That's a different error than the one you started with so it's possible we're getting somewhere ;). Can you create the simplest example needed to recreate the current issue and post it to http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I'm using too many libraries for jsfiddle. I'm going to make a new application from scratch to better understand backbone instead of elaborating on a demo. Since my original issue was solved I accepted your answer. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I can understand your reasoning for wanting to start from scratch but can't help thinking it's a bit drastic. I reckon it should be easy enough to solve your problem if you created a fiddle. It's dead easy to link to external libraries and I'm guessing all you'll need to recreate the problem is jQuery, backbone and the local storage plug-in. I bet you could do it in 10 minutes.

Comment: Since I encountered the same error when starting from scratch i made a new topic for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853612/backbone-localstorage-cannot-read-property-deferred-of-undefined

Comment: Yay! Works like a charm, now model gets updated. Thanks!