# Backbone localstorage: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I am trying to make a backbone application work with the localstorage plugin. I included the library after the backbone library.

I added the following line to my collection:

```
window.ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Product,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("ProductCollection")
});
```

I keep getting the following error from backbone.localstorage.js:
*Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined*

Is there anything i forgot to do in the implementation of the library? [Documentation](http://documentup.com/jeromegn/backbone.localStorage) says you only need to add the localstorage to your collection.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uDGb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzCvX/2/), and despite what I said in the other thread, it was a bit of a faff! Your error was to do with the order you were importing the libraries (Backbone depends on Underscore and jQuery, `Backbone.LocalStorage` relies on Backbone). The most reliable way of getting the order right in the fiddle was to add the CDN links in order to the external resources tab.

Your code is running for me in Chrome with no errors and I can inspect the data saved to local storage using the resources tab in dev tools. I would suggest checking you're using all the latest versions of the various libraries in your local build.

Comment: I have the same order in my HTML: <script src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah that looks right but it's not the order the fiddle was spitting out. Have a look at the forked version of your fiddle I link to above. In my tests it's working as expected.

Comment: It does work in the fiddle... So why not on my local webserver?

Comment: Could be an issue with version compatibility. I just grabbed the latest CDN links from here :- http://cdnjs.com/

Comment: I got it working, I had backbone 0.9.2 instead of 1.0.0. Thank you so much really, greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hey no worries, glad we got there in the end. Good luck with the rest of your project.